# Create multi choice list view with search box in Android

Tags: android, listview

I'm having a list of around more than 100 items that I'm building a multi choice list, out of which user can select as many items he needs. 
I created the list view with multi choice selection but scrolling the 100 items is too complex for user.

Is there any way to put the search box at the top of list view so upon typing the text in search box user will see only related items and can make a multi choice selection out of that?

Answer (score 2):

> is there any way to put the search box at the top of list view so
>   upon typing the text in search box user will see only related items
>   and can make a multi choice selection out of that?

Yes this is possible you have to implement the Text-watcher class.
In search edit-text you have to set `addTextChange Event`  and pass the text-watcher object in that.

Now in `OnTextChanged()` of the `TextWatcher` class you have to fetch the relevant data from your data source and refresh the adapter by `adapter.NotifyDatasetChanged()`.

**Edit**

Now for `Multiple selection List-view` you can create a `list-row layout` which has one `Checkbox`. In you class create a class of `Adapter`.You can create a `Base-Adapter` and it's `getView()` method inflate the `list-row` and set the text on the `check-box` and set the `checked` property of the `checkbox` according to your selection

Comment: thanks dharmendra for response,
actually I can add the search box to the list view, but not for the multi choice list view..

will u please let me know how to add for the multi choice selection

Answer (score 0):

yes,
you can use  **AutoCompleteTextView** or implement **EditText's onTextChangeListener** in top of listview.you can add listview's items into adapter into AutoCompleteTextView.

Hope u get what i say...

Comment: Hi richa, is it possible for the multi choice items list.. ?

Comment: yes its possible,http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html refer

Answer (score 0):

here is some code i tried.. it may help

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        len=actv.getText().length();

                        for(int i=0;i<content.size();i++)
                        {
                            if(len<=content.get(i).length())
                            {
                                if(actv.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase((String) content.get(i).subSequence(0, len)))
                                {

                                    arr_sort.add(content.get(i));

                                }


                            }

                        }

                        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyListDemoActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr_sort);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });
```